# Ant Design Tabs: hide more element

Tags: tabs, antd, ellipsis

I need left tabs with two items with component [Tabs](https://ant.design/components/tabs/) (ant.design).
This component shows me *"more element"* and I don't now how hide it.
[image]

My code:

```
...
const tabItems = [
    {label:'Tab 1',key:'1',children:'Content of Tab 1'},
    {label:'Tab 2',key:'2',children:'Content of Tab 2'},
]
...
return (
    ...
    <Tabs
        tabPosition="left"
        items={tabItems}
    />
    ...
)
```

When I use three or more items - it's works fine:
[image]

--- updated ---
I found crutch solution.
Add to component styles:

```
.ant-tabs-nav-operations {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is:
the total height beyond your Tabs is smaller than Tabs self.
Try the three method below:

```
1.Be sure the box is bigger than Tabs: 
<div class="box" style={{height: '100%'}}><Tabs/></div>.
2.Tabs props: 
<Tabs moreIcon={null} />
3.css hide: 
.ant-tabs-nav-operations {
    display: none !important; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you confirm your render isn't wrong? If not, here's an updated code and it works like it should

```
const {  Tabs  } = antd;


const onChange = (key) => {
  console.log(key);
};
const tabItems = [
    {label:'Tab 1',key:'1',children:'Content of Tab 1'},
    {label:'Tab 2',key:'2',children:'Content of Tab 2'},
]

const App = () => (
  <Tabs
tabPosition={'left'}
    items={tabItems}
  />
);

const ComponentDemo = App;


ReactDOM.render(<ComponentDemo />, mountNode);
```

[image: screenshot of the antd tab component]